# Published custom .NET Backend broke Azure Easy Tables

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-files

I was following the Microsoft Azure [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/#work-with-tables) to integrate my Xamarin Forms app with azure mobile services. I defined a data connection, used easy tables to define some custom tables and everything was working as expected with the mobile client.

Today I wanted to extend my backend functionality and also enable file storage. I followed the instructions found [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-blob-storage/) and as soon as I created a new .NET server backend project with a StorageController and published it to azure, the entire easy table api stopped working. All calls from the mobile client fail with the following error:

`The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

This happens for all `mobileClient.GetTable<SomeEntity>().SomeOperationAsync()` calls.

My guess is that publishing the custom backend overwrote the online generated easy tables api... unfortunately I don't have enough experience with the azure cloud to figure out where I made a mistake. Is there any way of getting the auto generated easy tables api to also work with file storage?

Comment: Easy table is only available in Node, and it seems that you are doing Easy Table + Node in the portal, then publishing File Storage + .NET backend which overwrites it (Node and .NET backends cannot really coexist). You will need to use the Node backend.

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you for clearing that up. I will stick to the easy tables api and find another way to store file. Using Azure Storage directly without the files wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mimi noted in the comments, Easy Tables is only available for the supplied Node backend, deployed from the portal.  If you are using your own code and publishing that, Easy Tables and Easy API will be disabled.

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you for clearing that up. I will stick to the easy tables api and find another way to store file. Using Azure Storage directly without the files wrapper. I am building a fast prototype so I don't want to write all my table controllers by hand especially if the schema is still volatile in our ongoing design.